# How to list all the threads running on different weblogic managed servers running on different nodes in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

How to list all the threads running on different weblogic managed servers running on different nodes in JAVA.

Does weblogic managed servers shares the threads.

Below is the code i am trying to find and close thread.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
boolean isAlive = false;
Thread oldThread = null;
for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
if (t.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("CompleteSyncThread")) {
    System.out.println("Thread is running  "+t.getName());
    isAlive = true;
    oldThread = t;
    break;
 }
}    

if(isAlive) {
   System.out.println("Killing old Thread --->  "+oldThread.getName());
   try {
      oldThread.stop();
   } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
} else {
   System.out.println("Starting new Thread --->  ");
   Thread thread = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
          Thread.currentThread().setName("CompleteSyncThread");
          // My Code
       }
    }};
   executor.submit(thread);
}
```

It is absolutely working fine on my local WL.
I want this to work on PROD environment with 6 managed servers under single WL admin server.
How can i do this?

Comment: every managed server is a different JVM, so they don't share threads

Comment: ...and creating/stopping your own threads in JEE environment is not a really good idea.